# How can i get Name of the server through eclipse plug in?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, websphere

I created eclipse plugin named "Name of server" which will be displayed in popup menu of the server.
Now i want to retrieve the server name when i click on "Name of server".
How can i get name of server ?

I am using IBM WebSphere Application servers

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It isn't very clear what "server" names you want to find (Clusters? Nodes? Profiles?), how they should be linked to Eclipse entities (the standard "server configurations"? Something custom in projects? Global WAS-related information?), and what are you intending to do beyond the functionality of the existing WAS plugin.

In general, you can either inspect files and directories in the WAS installation (e.g. *profiles/* in version 8.5) or rely on the commandline administration tools (or, better, the underlying Java classes). All highly version-specific, of course.